# Finding subsentences from one singular sentence

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of possible subsentences from a single given sentence in Python, but cannot figure out how to do so.

For example:

```
sentence_1 = 'the dog jumped around'
```

and I want to split it into:

```
['the',
 'the dog'
 'dog jumped'
 'jumped around'
 'the dog jumped'
 'dog jumped around'
 'the dog jumped around'
 ]
```

Comment: Why don't you want just 'dog' in the list?

Comment: Please better define the rules of the "subsentences"

Comment: So 'the' is a subsententence, but 'dog' is not? and 'jumped' is not? and 'around'?

Comment: Hi! I am so sorry, you are completely right, I would also want to add 'dog', 'jumped', 'around' to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have all subsentence of at least 2 words:

```
sentence_1 = 'the dog jumped around'

words = sentence_1.split()

data = []
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(i + 2, len(words) + 1):
        data.append(" ".join(words[i:j]))
print(data)
```

As you also want the first word:

```
data.append(words[0])
```

**Output:**

```
['the', 'the dog', 'the dog jumped', 'the dog jumped around', 'dog jumped', 'dog jumped around', 'jumped around']
```

I have to admit I don't really understand why `'the'` has to be in the list, but not `'dog'`, `'jumped'` nor `'around'`

---

To have ***all*** subsentences:

```
sentence_1 = 'the dog jumped around'

words = sentence_1.split()

data = []
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(words) + 1):
        data.append(" ".join(words[i:j]))
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['the', 'the dog', 'the dog jumped', 'the dog jumped around', 'dog', 'dog jumped', 'dog jumped around', 'jumped', 'jumped around', 'around']
```

Comment: thank you so much! the second part is exactly what I needed to do. In my original question, I forgot to add that I wanted all singular words printed out in the list as well.

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!

Comment: I just have an extension to the question: I am trying to create a function that creates two different sublists, for two different given sentence arguments. When I add this code into the function, it runs for the first sentence argument given. When I then change variable names and try to have it run for the second sentence as well, nothing happens and only the sublist for the first argument is given. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Here's how I would do it: https://onecompiler.com/python/3xtqwy689.